# Error: No Provider for Store! in @ngrx 4.x

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

When migrating my project from @ngrx 2.x to 4.1.0, I encountered the error message

> NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!

The store was imported as shown in the [docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md):

```
import { StoreModule as NgRxStoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgRxStoreModule.forRoot(reducerMap, {
      initialState: initial
    }),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects)
  ],
  providers: [AppActions]
})
export class StoreModule {}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out that some of my services imported the store via

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store/src/store'
```

Changing the imports to

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store'
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: That auto import :@

Comment: I had a similar issue with auto import in Web Storm adding "@ngrx/store/store"

Answer (score 0):

I got this while I was trying to run tests in angular 7.

The solution for me was to:

1. define a store mock in the body of `describe`:

```
let storeMock;
```

2. initialize it in `beforeEach` section:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    storeMock = {
      dispatch: jasmine.createSpy("dispatch"),
      pipe: jasmine.createSpy("pipe").and.returnValue(from([{
...
        requestTimeout: 5000,
...
      }]))
    };
```

3. define provider for Store in `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

````
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        ...
        {
          provide: Store,
          useValue: storeMock
        }
        ...
      ]
    });
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For ngrx 8 use:

```
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
```